# How to define an instance variable from a model used in Rails partial _header

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
application.html.erb
<html>
.
.
.
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
</body>
.
.
.
</html>
```

An instance variable from my Article model is used in a dropdown of the header.

```
_header.html.erb 
.
.
<li class="dropdown">
.
.
<%= link_to(@articles.first.source, target: "_blank") do %>
.
.
</li>
.
.
```

Do I have to include @articles = Articles.all in every view, such as:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

def index 
  @articles = Article.approved.all
end

def new
  @articles = Article.approved.all
end

def show 
  @articles = Article.approved.all
end 

etc
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: Is the misspelling deliberate? (If so, it's *terribly* confusing.)

Comment: no that was an accident. fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_articles

  def index 
  end

  def new
  end

  def show 
  end 

  private

  def set_articles
    @articles = Article.approved.all
  end

end
```

This will set **@articles** before all your actions and so you won't need to repeat yourself.

Comment: So this still has to be done for every different controller? Or is there a way to do it universally?

Comment: You may do it in your ApplicationController and it will be valid to all controllers, 'cause they all descend from ApplicationsController.

Answer (score 2):

instance variables are used class wide. so you don't need to  do that as the variable is available through out your controller class, however if you want it to populate it with all the articles then you can separate it into a function which you can call in each method. better idea would be to use a callback to call the new function

**Edit: say thanks to @Ed de Almeida He did it for you.**

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the url source to appear on the dropdown menu on every page of the site. Is it always the same url?  If so, you can define it as a constant. There are several gems you can use to set up secure global variables, such as [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) and [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro). Or you can define it in the different config/environments/ files - production.rb and development.rb

```
config.foo = 'bar'
```

You can then get access to it with

```
Rails.application.config.foo
```

If they are not constants, you could set up a before_action in the application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_dropdown_articles

  def set_dropdown_articles
    @dropdown_articles = Article.approved.all
  end
end
```

Comment: So this still has to be done for every different controller? Or is there a way to do it universally?

Comment: Since this is defined on the ApplicationController, you only do it the once as all your controllers inherit from ApplicationController.